# how to call member methods inside a wrapper class without repeating the method definition inside the wrapper class?

Tags: class, visual-c++, wrapper

let's assume i have a wrapper class that embeds a single memeber:

```
class wrapper {
    public:
    Object obj;
     // the rest ...
   };
```

if the member variable obj has some methods, how can i call the member variable method without explicitly defining methods in the wrapper class like this?

```
class wrapper{ 

public:


    void foo { obj.foo ();    }
    int bar (int x) {return obj.bar(x);    }


};
```

i know this is doable in python, but how can i have the same functionality in c++?

ps- please note i don't want to inherit from the member class. this wouldn't't be a wrapper class by definition. i want to achieve this through composition instead.

Comment: Maybe have the `wrapper` class inherit from the `Object` class

Comment: i should have added i want to do it through composition and not inheritance. is it doable?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle this. One would be to create a getter to return the `wrapper` object and another is to override the typecast operator:

```
class Object {
public:
    void foo() {cout << "test" << endl;}
};

class wrapper {
protected:
    Object obj;
public:
    operator Object&() {return obj;}
    Object& getObject() {return obj;}
};

void f(A& a) {
    a.foo();
}

int main() {
    wrapper w;
    ((Object)w).foo();
    w.getObject().foo();
    f(w);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the typecast operator requires you to cast the `wrapper` object, except when passing as a parameter to the function `f()`.

Also, in your example you already have the `obj` member as `public` so it is exposed. You could just:

```
wrapper w;
w.obj.foo();
```

Here's a discussion on that: [What good are public variables then?](http://What%20good%20are%20public%20variables%20then?)